# Assigning factor levels to observations using more than one numeric vector

Tags: r

I apologize in advance for the clunky title but i have no idea how to define what I want to do more precisely.

First I'll generate a small sample of the data:

```
data<-data.frame("ID"=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 "emp.num"=c(2,3,100,150,250,300,400,500,600),
                 "rev"=c(10,80,100,200,300,50,300,350,350))
```

Which looks like this:

```
  ID emp.num rev
1  A       2  10
2  A       3  80
3  A     100 100
4  B     150 200
5  B     250 300
6  B     300  50
7  C     400 300
8  C     500 350
9  C     600 350
```

Where "ID" is the firm name, "emp.num" represents the number of employees in the firm, and "rev" represents revenue.

What I would like to do is create a factor variable(Size) which categorizes the firms into "small", "medium" and "large" according to the following principle:

small: firms with rev(0,65] and emp.num (0,50]

medium: firms with rev(65,260] and emp.num (50,250]

large: rev>260 and emp.num>250

So in the end I want to get this:

```
  ID emp.num rev Size
1  A       2  10    S
2  A       3  80    M
3  A     100 100    M
4  B     150 200    M
5  B     250 300    L
6  B     300  50    L
7  C     400 300    L
8  C     500 350    L
9  C     600 350    L
```

This would of course be an easy problem using the cut() function if I wanted to create a factor variable from only a single numeric(let's say only from rev or only from emp.num) but I'm at a complete loss as to how to "cut" when I want to use 2 variables like this

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Do you have a question? See [ask] if you need a guidance.

Answer (score 1):

What about this using `findInterval`?

```
ind <- pmax(findInterval(data$emp.num, c(0, 50, 250, Inf)),
       findInterval(data$rev, c(0, 65, 260, Inf)))

cbind(data, size = c("Small", "Medium", "Large")[ind])
  ID emp.num rev   size
1  A       2  10  Small
2  A       3  80 Medium
3  A     100 100 Medium
4  B     150 200 Medium
5  B     250 300  Large
6  B     300  50  Large
7  C     400 300  Large
8  C     500 350  Large
9  C     600 350  Large
```

Comment: Thanks! Glad to hear that from an expert! :)

Comment: Wow, didn't even know that function existed, very simple and elegant, thanks!

Comment: On second thought I encountered a problem with your solution. If i understand it correctly, the 'pmax' function will check whether emp.num or rev is the bigger number, and will procced to check in which interval that bigger number falls and accordingly classify it(Small, Medium, Big). The problem with the pmax approach is for example if the firm has emp.num=51, and rev=64. Since rev is the bigger number your algorithm only checks rev, and according to the specified intervals if rev=64 the firm is small. But actually it is medium since emp.num=51

Comment: So if for example emp.num=2, and rev=1000, and I use pmin wont that classify the firm as small since emp.num<50, but it's actually large since rev>260? I have a feeling some sort of 'and' conditional is needed somewhere..

Comment: The problem is, that you don't clarify in your question the cases where one variable falls into one interval and the other falls in another. If a higher value has more importance, use `pmax`, if lower value ist more important, use `pmin`

Comment: Hmm, maybe the way I stated it originally was unclear. When I wrote: "small: firms with rev(0,65] and emp.num (0,50]" what I meant is that both the conditions have to be met in order for the firm to be classified as "small". If either condition is not met(rev>65 or emp.num>50) the firm is automatically "Medium" sized. The way I see it both rev and emp.num. values are of equal importance since they both have to be satisfied. So whether I use `pmin` or `pmax` makes no difference since which of the two conditions is 'picked' says nothing about whether the other condition is respected.

Comment: In the comment above you say that `emp.num=51`, which is `medium`, and `rev=64`, which is `small`, and you then say that it actually is `small`. So it seems that the lower level is more important for you, or?

Comment: Sorry was away from my computer for the last few days. Anyway, in the above comment I stated that the firm is actually `small` not `medium` since `emp.num=51` which is >50. So in this case the lower number was more important yes, but that is not true in all cases, since the data could conceivably show `emp.num=2` and `rev=1000` for a firm, in which case the larger number would be more important

Comment: Then you have to define a more sophisticated decision rule, then I will try to help you to implement that in R...